# Outlook 365 Attach Recent Files list doesn't work; M1 Mac; Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, attachments

When attaching files to emails in Outlook on my Mac, the Recent Files list does not work.  I must always click Browse My Mac, which is a lot more clicks.  Its list of Recent Files never changes.  Is there a way to clear this list?  Shouldn't it be the same list of Recents that I see in Finder?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur recently? If so, have you done any specific operations before that?

On the other hand, it's suggested that you could try to quit Outlook and re-open it to check if there're any difference.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.